# What is the purpose of this switch to the left of the filter?

Tags: switch

What is the purpose of this switch to the left in the picture?  Thank you!

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhnVO.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhnVO.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P192.jpg)[image]

Comment: No photos attached

Comment: Thank you!  I didn’t realize the original picture hadn’t loaded bc the file was too big.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a pressure sensor.   When the filter gets dirty, it's harder to push air through it and the air pressure in that location goes up.   Can you trace the wire?  Do you have an indicator that says "Change Air Filter"?.

Or, it may be to stop the furnace from running unless the panel is in place and against the button.